# SSI package Export data from view

Tags: ssis, export

How make SSIS package, which can export data from view when number of columns is variety.
I can't rebuild my package after deploy, this is basic condition!

Answer (score 2):

SSIS connection managers require consistent schemas to define the columns in the sources and destinations.  Pick another tool.